# scipy interp2d is slow

Tags: pandas, scipy

I'm using scipy.interpolate.interp2d function and it returns the expected results however there is a delay in milliseconds. Is there a way to speed it up?

[image]
Parameters:
s = 0.001 and t = 4

vols = data from the url https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/alquadri.com/uploads/vols_data.txt

Following is the function that I'm using.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd
    
def InterpVols2d(vols, s, t):
    df = pd.DataFrame(vols, columns=['x','y','z'])
    VolsPivotTable = df.pivot_table(values='z', index='y', columns='x').ffill().bfill()          ## Forward then back fill
    # print(VolsPivotTable)

    ### Get the Matrix from the volumes data
    CapFloorVolMatrixNP = np.array(vols)
    x = np.unique(CapFloorVolMatrixNP[:,0])
    y = np.unique(CapFloorVolMatrixNP[:,1])
    Z = []
    for counter, item in enumerate(y):
        Z.append(VolsPivotTable.iloc[counter,:].tolist())
    z = np.array(Z)

    ### Interp2d 
    interp2dData = interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear')(s,t)[0]  #fill_value=np.nan
    return interp2dData
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It's building the spline fit at construction time, and that takes time.

interpn/RGI is faster for startup.